# Square Brackets Javascript Object Key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can anyone explain how the why/how the below method of assigning keys in JavaScript works?

```
a = "b"
c = {[a]: "d"}
```

return:

```
Object {b: "d"}
```

Answer (score 261, accepted):

It's the new ES2015 (the EcmaScript spec formally known as ES6) [computed property name syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names).  It's a shorthand for the `someObject[someKey]` assignment that you know from ES3/5:

```js
var a = "b"
var c = {[a]: "d"}
```

is syntactic sugar for:

```js
var a = "b"
var c = {}
c[a] = "d"
```

Comment: So til ES2022, [ ] can be Array Literal Constructor, Property Accessor, Computed Property Names, Destructuring Assignment, Binding Element (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37691566/9182265). I doubt there's more.

Comment: Yep... JavaScript is a bit of a mess nowadays to be honest. A case of too many cooks.

Answer (score 56):

Really the use of `[]` gives an excellent way to use actual value of variable as **key**`/`**property** while creating JavaScript **objects**.

> I'm pretty much statisfied with the above answer and I appreciate it as it allowed me to write this with a little example.
>
> I've executed the code line by line on **Node REPL** (Node shell).

```
> var key = "fullName";     // Assignment
undefined
>
> var obj = {key: "Rishikesh Agrawani"}    // Here key's value will not be used
undefined
> obj     // Inappropriate, which we don't want
{ key: 'Rishikesh Agrawani' }
>
> // Let's fix
undefined
> var obj2 = {[key]: "Rishikesh Agrawani"}
undefined
> obj2
{ fullName: 'Rishikesh Agrawani' }
>
```

Answer (score 27):

```
const animalSounds = {cat: 'meow', dog: 'bark'};

const animal = 'lion';

const sound = 'roar';

{...animalSounds, [animal]: sound};
```

The result will be

```
{cat: 'meow', dog: 'bark', lion: 'roar'};
```

Answer (score 6):

Also, only condition to use `[]` notation for accessing or assigning stuff in objects when we don't yet know what it's going to be until evaluation or runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I want to make an object but I don't know the name of the `key` until runtime.

Back in the ES5 days:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject[key] = "bar";
```

Writing two lines of code is so painful... Ah, ES6 just came along:

```
var myObject = {[key]:"bar"};
```

If the value of `key` equals `foo`, then both approaches result in:

```
{foo : "bar"}
```