# why array like syntax is used when dynamically setting react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is a function in `react`

For setting a `state` dynamically we usually do

```
handleChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

But if we put the name manually then array is not needed.

```
handleChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value})
}
```

Could someone tell why we put the `e.target.name` in `array like syntax` when `dynamically` fetching the `name`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Square Brackets Javascript Object Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515598/square-brackets-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's ES6 syntax, it's called a *computed key*. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837916/creating-object-with-dynamic-keys) for a bit more detail, but essentially whatever `e.target.name` is, it'll be set as the object key.

```
handleChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

It's the same as doing this in ES5 (more verbose):

```
handleChange: function (e) {
    var state = {};

    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;

    this.setState(state);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript evaluates the keys of objects as strings. So, [e.target.name] means access the key whose name is the value of e.target.name (cast to a string), while name: is interpreted as the key whose name is 'name'.