# Meaning of var [foo] = bar?

Tags: javascript, variables, declaration

I seen a code snippet like the below. Can anybody please tell me what

```
var [input] = data; var [checkbox, payee, amount]  = data2;
```

means?

```
function example(data,data2){
var [input] = data;
var [checkbox, payee, amount]  = data2;
............
............
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Square Brackets Javascript Object Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515598/square-brackets-javascript-object-key)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Comment: it's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) by taking an array as value to assign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with an array/iterable object (with implemented [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator)) with values to assign.

The value goes into the variable with the same index as the given data.

For getting only some parts at a certain index, you could use an object with indices as keys.

```js
var array = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten'];
    [zero, one] = array,
    { 3: three, 10: ten } = array;
    
console.log(zero);
console.log(one);
console.log(three);
console.log(ten);
```

Answer (score 2):

As [Nina Scholz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) stated in her comment, it's a destructuring assignment.

If `data2` was an array of `[1, 2, 3]`, then `var [checkbox, payee, amount]  = data2;` is the same as:

```
    var checkbox = data2[0]; // 1
    var payee = data2[1]; // 2
    var amount = data2[2]; // 3
```

### **Rest parameter**

You can using destructuring with rest parameter like in the example below, to save multiple elements into an array.

```js
const digits = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const [one, ...other] = digits;
console.log(one);
console.log(other);
```

### Omitting values

You can ignore the values you're not interested in, **like this**:

```js
const myArray = ["car", "cat", "house", "dog", "window", "mouse"];
const [, cat, ,dog, , mouse] = myArray;
console.log(cat, dog, mouse);
```

**or like this**:

```js
const myArray = ["John", "Mary", "Steve", 0, 1, 2];
const [name1, name2, name3] = myArray;
console.log(name1, name2, name3);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
var t = [1,2];

var [a,b] = t;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

When used on arrays, it assigns consecutive array elements to variables introduced at the left side of the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

This is [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to **unpack values from arrays, or properties from
>   objects, into distinct variables**.

As per your example,

```
var data = [1];
var [input] = data;
console.log(input); //1
```