# React-select multi not working the way it's defined in the documentation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I am using react-select to make a searchable dropdown menu. And it's working fine until you actually select an option, then it just throws an `Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.` error, doesn't remove the option you have picked and doesn't show what you have picked so far.
My options are an array with objects `{value: crew.id, label: crew.code}`, and here is my Select component

```
<Select
    isMulti
    name='teamIdsFilter'
    menuPosition='fixed'
    options={crewOptions}
    value={teamIds}
    placeholder='Nepasirinktas'
    onChange={event => this.handleTeamIdsSelect(event)} />
```

And my handleTeamIdsSelect event handler

```
handleTeamIdsSelect = (event) => {
    if (event) {
        const selectedCrew = event.map(crew => crew.value);
        this.setState({teamIds: selectedCrew});
    }
};
```

Comment: maybe you are not updating state properly

Comment: after selecting it returns an array with selected object, so everything is ok with updating the state. The react-select component is not working the same way it's described in the documentation.

Comment: then you have to double check the complete document, you might have missed some silly things

Comment: [Actual documentation](https://react-select.com/home#getting-started) I am pretty sure I haven't missed anything, because there isn't much to miss, the component just does not work the same way for me.

Comment: @AmruthLS you were right, the event handler was the problem, I only stored the value of the event, when I needed to store the whole event (the array with objects) to the state. But they should have mentioned it in the documentation though, because i thought that it will return the same event as the regular material-ui select would.

Comment: good to here, you resolved :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using multi instead of isMulti. This will fix the problem.

```
<Select
    multi
    name='teamIdsFilter'
    menuPosition='fixed'
    options={crewOptions}
    value={teamIds}
    placeholder='Nepasirinktas'
    onChange={event => this.handleTeamIdsSelect(event)} />
```

Comment: Adding `multi` is the same like adding `bananas`; At first I thought  you were correct and it made my error disappear; However, it just means your Select component is now single-item select, not multi ! (Checked this with v3.1.0 in Oct/2020)

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
const changeSelect2 = (name,value)=>{
    setFormState((preValue)=>{
        return {
        ...preValue, // use spead sign for join 
        [name] : value // lec 43 // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515598/square-brackets-javascript-object-key
        }
    });
}

<Select options={crewOptions}  onChange={(res)=>{changeSelect2('teamIdsFilter',res.value)}} name="teamIdsFilter" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
        this.state = {
            isMulti:true,
        };


<Select  isMulti={this.state.isMulti}/>
```

Comment: this simply does not make sense is the same as isMulti

Answer (score -1):

try adding

> multi={true}

hopefully it will work.

Comment: Here is the silly thing that worked for me.  after isMulti  make sure to hit enter again.  fixed the problem