# How to use args as a json field

Tags: javascript, json

I want to use this function

```js
function setPlayerInternalData(playerid, key, value) {
    server.UpdateUserInternalData({
        playfabid: playerid,
        data: {
            key: value
        }
    });
}
```

where key is set by any string I submit to it.
it works for value but idk how to make it work for key.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: use `[key]: value`, Read about [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 1):

use `[]` to wrap the key.

```js
let myKey = 'three';
let myValue = '4';

let myObj = {
  [myKey]: myValue
};

console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

> **Note:** I had answered the similar problem at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53123018/6615163 and this is also useful.

```
...
data: {
    key: value
}
```

to

```
...
data: {
    [key]: value
}
```

It will work.

For more info, check below.

```
> language = "JavaScript"
'JavaScript'
> 
> o = {language}
{ language: 'JavaScript' }
> 
> o2 = {language: language}
{ language: 'JavaScript' }
> 
> // Let's fix
undefined
> 
> o3 = {[language]: language}
{ JavaScript: 'JavaScript' }
>
```