# Cloud Functions: Values not read in Map

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Why am I unable to read the following variables in a nested map?

```
for (const key in doc.data().category) {
  const location = doc.data().location;  // declared but it's value is never read"
  const mainCategory = doc.data().category; // declared but it's value is never read"
  const subCategory = doc.data().category[key]; // declared but it's value is never read"

  categoryCount.doc('categoryCount')
  .set({ location: { mainCategory: { subCategory: "test" } } }, 
  { merge: true })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Console logs to clarify:

```
console.log(location); // "New York"
const map = { location: { mainCategory: { subCategory: true } } };
console.log(map);  // "location": {"mainCategory": {"subCategory": true}}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is.  What do you mean by "declared but it's value never read"?

Comment: @DougStevenson I've added console logs to clarify. I can't get the values when using the variables in a map. The TSLint error is "declared but it's value is never read".

Comment: What do you expect the code to do instead of what it's doing now?

Comment: @DougStevenson Return the actual data of the variable, not variable name. So, return "New York": {"Running": {"Race":true}}, instead of "location": {"mainCategory": {"subCategory": true}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the value of a variable as the name of a property, you have to tell JavaScript that you want to insert that value (as opposed to just naming the key):

```
{ [location]: { mainCategory: { subCategory: "test" } } }
```

Notice the square brackets around `location`.

See also: [Square Brackets Javascript Object Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515598/square-brackets-javascript-object-key)

Comment: Ah ok! I didn't know that - it's working now. Thanks so much :) Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be misunderstanding how JavaScript objects work.  Imagine you have three variables called:

```
var A = 'X';
var B = 'Y';
var C = 'Z';
```

when you code:

```
{
  A: {
    B: {
      C: "test"
    }
  }
}
```

You do **not** end up with an object of value:

```
{
   X: {
     Y: {
       Z: "test"
     }
   }
}
```

If that is what you want, consider:

```
var O1 = {};
O1[C] = "test";
var O2 = {};
O2[B] = O1;
var O3 = {};
O3[A] = O2;

// O3 is the top level object
```