# can I dynamically change the key and value when updating Firestore document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

so I have callable cloud function like this:

```
const db = admin.firestore()

exports.changeEventDataInUserSubcollection = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {


    const updatedKey = data.updatedKey
    const updatedValue = data.updatedValue
    const creatorID = data.creatorID
    const eventID = data.eventID

    try {

        return db.doc(`users/${creatorID}/createdEvents/${eventID}`).update({updatedKey: updatedValue})


    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return Promise.resolve(null)
    }


})
```

as you can see in `.update({updatedKey: updatedValue})`, I want to set the key and value from the client side. so I can update the document dynamically. I want the `updatedKey` and `updatedValue` come from client side

but my code above seems will not work, because I have this warning:

[image]

`updatedKey` is declared but never used. so how to dynamically change the key and value when updating Firestore document ? can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here doesn't have anything to do with Cloud Functions or Firestore.  It's JavaScript syntax.  If you want to use the value of a variable as the key of an object you, need to use [square bracket syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515598/square-brackets-javascript-object-key) for the object:

```
return db
    .doc(`users/${creatorID}/createdEvents/${eventID}`)
    .update({ [updatedKey]: updatedValue })
```

Note the square brackets around `updatedKey` that tell JavaScript that you want to substitute the value of the variable as the name of the key.

You could have achieved the same thing like this:

```
const object = {}
object[updatedKey] = updatedValue

return db
    .doc(`users/${creatorID}/createdEvents/${eventID}`)
    .update(object)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a dynamic key you need to do do something like this

```js
 return db.doc(`users/${creatorID}/createdEvents/${eventID}`).update({[updatedKey]: updatedValue});
```