# [] : {} syntax in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have following source code:

```
const positions = {
  [modules.module1.tasks.t1.id]: { modifier: 1 },
};
```

Anybody can explain or link to documentation what is done above?

Comment: can you add respective code to understand.

Comment: `{ modifier: 1 }` is just a normal object as you would expect. `{ [foo]: bar }` is just creating a new object where `foo` a variable string (unlike `modifier`). An alternative for the former is `{ ['modifier']: 1 }` -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515598/square-brackets-javascript-object-key

Comment: So how to make minimum viable working code in: https://repl.it/@tomaszwaszczyk/in-TypeScript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing specific to TypeScript in your code sample. It's just modern JavaScript.

Let's decompose what is happening here:

```
[modules.module1.tasks.t1.id]
```

This is a *computed property name*. It means the `position` object will have a property equal to `modules.module1.tasks.t1.id`.

If `modules.module1.tasks.t1.id` is a string, then this property will be exactly the same. Otherwise, `modules.module1.tasks.t1.id` will be coerced into a string.

```
{ modifier: 1 }
```

Our dynamic property will have a value of `{ modifier: 1 }`. It's just a regular property assignment.

**Example**

```js
const modules = {
  module1: {
    tasks: {
      t1: {
        id: 'foo'
      }
    }
  }
}

const positions = {
  [modules.module1.tasks.t1.id]: { modifier: 1 },
}; // evaluates to { foo: { modifier: 1 } }
```