# Question about how javascript is able to update an object entry using square brackets containing a key as the property accessor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, accessor

based on a tutorial on youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiiaHyhhwBU&t=1195s) I am writing a chat application using react hooks in particular useReducer(). But I don't uderstand how in the switch case is returned an updated version of the state keeping just two elements and doesn't add a third element to the initState:

```
const initState = {
    general: [
        {from: 'ciro', msg: 'bella'},
        {from: 'ciro', msg: 'bella'},
        {from: 'ciro', msg: 'bella'}
    ],
    private: [
        {from: 'gennaro', msg: 'hello'},
        {from: 'gennaro', msg: 'hello'},
        {from: 'gennaro', msg: 'hello'}
    ]
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    const { topic, from, msg } = action.payload;

    switch(action.type) {
        case 'RECEIVE_MESSAGE':
            return {
                ...state,
                [topic]: [
                    ...state[topic],
                    {
                        from: from,
                        msg: msg
                    }
                ]
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I wonder how is [topic] able to update the message list corresponding to the topic as it is not directly linked to ...state? and how to the ...state is not just added a third element? I find this very confusing.

```
            return {
                ...state,
                [topic]: [
                    ...state[topic],
                    {
                        from: from,
                        msg: msg
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Square Brackets Javascript Object Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515598/square-brackets-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Basically when you ask:

> how to the ...state is not just added a third element?

It's because:

> The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (ES2018) added spread properties to object literals. It copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object.
> **Shallow-cloning (excluding prototype) or merging of objects is now
> possible using a shorter syntax than Object.assign().**

If objects have a property with the same name, then the right-most object property overwrites the previous one.

Regarding:

> I wonder how is [topic] able to update the message list corresponding to the topic?

I think this: [Square Brackets Javascript Object Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515598/square-brackets-javascript-object-key) is very clear, if it is not please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: The first half of your answer really answered my question on the second half i think i didn't express myself really well as i was wondering how [topic] knows that needs to update a property of state as it is not directly linked to it, but you answered that on the first half. Very helpful, thank you!