# Why these brackets in this function setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, onchange, form-submit

My `onChange` handler for submitting a form with multiple input values and takes in whatever the name attribute of the given input field is. So i basically know what this code does, but i don't know exactly what happens under the hood.

Why the brackets in `[e.target.name]` ?
I also know that in this case `setFormData({ ...formData, name: e.target.value});` the function would every time just change the value of the input field with the attribute name.

```js
const Register = ({ setAlert, register, isAuthenticated }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name:"",
    email:"",
    password: "",
    password2: ""
  }); 

  const {name, email, password, password2} = formData;

  const onChange = e => 
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
```

Would be nice if somebody would know it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Square Brackets Javascript Object Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515598/square-brackets-javascript-object-key)

Comment: yess, definitively thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) : ... is for take all properties(with the values of course) of an array or object

  ```
  const arr = ["a", "b","c"];

  const arr2 = [...arr, "d"];

  // arr2 -> ["a", "b","c", "d"]
  ```
- the backets are used to put a variable value as a property

  ```
  const prop = "myProp";
  const obj = {[prop] : "value"}
  // obj -> {myProp : value}
  ```

Comment: @peewee99 don't hesitate to mark this response as "solved", it may help other people