# JavaScript: Firebase Realtime Database write Data but Variable in dictionary is not recognized

Tags: javascript, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I want to write my Data in a Firebase Realtime Database, but the problem is that the first value of the child should have the value of a variable but the variable is not recognized at variable.
It should look like this:

[image: In the child it displays two variables]

so I tried:

```
let id = chatid + "::::" + username;
let input = document.getElementById('input').value;
 
firebase.database().ref('chat/'+ chatid + "/chat").set({
   id: input
})
```

but the id variable is not recognized as a variable, thats why in the firebase console it looks like this:

[image: Instead of the value variable, the name of variable "id" is displayed to me]

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do as follows:

```
let id = chatid + "::::" + username;
let input = document.getElementById('input').value;

firebase
    .database()
    .ref('chat/' + chatid + '/chat/' + id)
    .set(input);
```

or as follows:

```
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('chat/' + chatid + '/chat')
    .set({
      [id]: input,
    });
```

More detail on the square brackets approach in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515598/square-brackets-javascript-object-key).