# Not able to pass dynamic headers using Fetch in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass dynamic header to Fetch API in React. But header name is not picking properly while passing it to back end.

GET functionality
[image]

And invoking this function from another component like this.

[image]

to the back end its being passed like this.

[image]

Expectation is : "user_id" : "yoga_1003"

Please suggest.

Comment: [Square bracket notation for dynamic object keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515598/square-brackets-javascript-object-key) 
`headers: { [header_name]: data }`